# How to query data in Oracle SQL that gives the max value of a column and the corresponding columns for that row?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a Oracle SQL query that I'm trying to get the MAX value of t4.workers column along with its corresponding columns in that row, but I only want to see one row for each project along with the max workers and the max date of the row with the max workers.

Example Data:

| project | date | vendor | workers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4012 | 01-JAN-21 | ABC | 6 |
| 4012 | 26-JAN-21 | ABC | 8 |
| 4012 | 12-JAN-21 | ABC | 8 |
| 4010 | 13-FEB-21 | ZZZ | 3 |
| 4010 | 02-FEB-21 | ZZZ | 5 |
| 4010 | 25-FEB-21 | ZZZ | 15 |

In the above example the outcome I want to see would be:

| project | date | vendor | workers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4010 | 25-FEB-21 | ZZZ | 15 |
| 4012 | 26-JAN-21 | ABC | 8 |

Below is my code:

```
SELECT
   t1.project,
   t2.date,
   t3.vendor,
   t4.workers

FROM t1, t2, t3, t4

WHERE t1 = t2
   AND t2 = t4
   AND t3 = t4;
```

Comment: it's not clear to me, Can you please post the tables' structure and explain the meaning of conditions like `t1=t2`; do you have columns `t1` and `t2`? in which tables?

Comment: @House .  . . Why are you not using proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax?  That said, using table names for join conditions is really confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `rank()` window function to assign a rank to each row per `project`. To define the order use the number of `workers` in descending order. Staring from `1` the rank is the lower the more `workers` there are in that row. So all the rows where this rank is `1` are the ones you want.

```
SELECT project,
       date,
       vendor,
       workers
       FROM (SELECT project,
                    date,
                    vendor,
                    workers,
                    rank() OVER (PARTITION BY project
                                 ORDER BY workers DESC) r
                    FROM elbat) x
       WHERE r = 1;
```

Note: This includes ties. If you don't want ties you can use `row_number()` instead of rank but then you'd need a second criteria for the order unless it is OK for you that one random row is picked from the tied ones.